# Installing a SSL certificate on dedicated ip with more than one domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, domain

This problem is a bit complex, but i will try to explain as best possible.

I am hosted on Bluehots, and I have a Dedicated ip address with them. they allow hosting multiple domains, so i have multiple hosted in one account.

The way they are setup is that domain1.com is the primary domain and is the root .../public_html/ all other domains... domain2.com, domain3.com etc. are hosted within the root i.e. /public_html/domain2/ and /public_html/domain3/ etc.

I can even access the content on domain2.com by going to domain1.com/domain2/ (which i redirect to domain2.com with .htaccess.

Whithout babbling on, here is the problem:
I want to install a ssl certificate to make domain1.com more secure, and since i have a dedicated ip it should be possible. But i just realized that i have other domains also hosted within my account so I foresee a problem. I am just not sure if i can still install a SSL cert or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a problem. What problem do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) certificates don't rely on the IP address but on the domain name. As long as your domain name can be found as common name or alternative name, you are fine.

There was a time when having multiple SSL virtual hosts behind one IP address was not possible but now most of the Web ecosystem supports [server name identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: How do I know if the certificate i have is x.509? I have th PossitiveSSL one found here: http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo.aspx

Comment: Don't worry about this, this is the standard.

Comment: Ok guys, so yesterday I did this and it worked, so thanks for the confidence you instilled in me. They then refereed me to this: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html ware they showed my domain and that I was actually working... but I want to know if my browsers was supposed to show that my site is safe ware the favicon is displayed. it still says this website does not supply identity information. I taught this process will also show my visitors that is was now secure. - Am I just mistaken?

Comment: This is where the SSL certificates business is taking over. What you're talking about is called [extended validation certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) and for that kind of certificates, you should to give a whole lot of money.

Comment: Oh I see, I taught all of them do that because it said "Trusted by all popular Browsers" that the browsers will display the content as safe. but can i be sure once it is installed it should make the communication with the server safer?

Comment: If the tool you used said it's OK, your configuration should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.

I've got a server with one IP address, and a half-dozen different sites, presenting on different hostnames, most with a different SSL certificate.

As long as your host allow you to specify different settings for each VirtualHost, I don't see why it'd be a problem, unless one of us is missing a massive detail from the facts

Comment: I don't think i missed anything... I was just worried because my host says that you need a dedicated ip if you want to use ssl certs because they host many domains in their normal ips and I taught that if I wanted to use ssl certs it would require me to have one domain for each ip or something. But seeing what you said gives me the impression that it is possible.